# Fixing a broken subversion setup

Tags: svn

In an really lazy moment, I updated a project by copying in and overwriting half its files with identical ones from a fork.  It seems I copied in some subversion info as well as every time I try to update I get conflicting messages.

The project works well.  I want to commit it exactly as is.  But Tortoise SVN seems to see the older mixed up data.

What is the command to remove all existing subversion info from a project on my hard drive and force it to commit as the the working version?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, do yourself a favour and back up what you've got before touching it any further!

Normally **`svn export`** would be the command to use to clean out the `.svn` dirs. You can run the command on a working copy to remove `.svn` dirs in-place, or you can export to a separate directory. But I couldn't say for sure whether it will work on a directory tree with "unusual" `.svn` directories.

TortoiseSVN can do exports too of course. Note for doing it in-place, TortoiseSVN has a trick you can do of right-click dragging a directory onto itself, and then choosing "export". The trick is you have to drag the directory onto itself *in another window*.

Once you have a tree without `.svn` dirs, do a fresh checkout somewhere else. Then, copy your previously-exported tree over the top of the checkout.

How does that sound?

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- remove the .svn directory (thus removing all subversion information)
- checkout the repository that you want your code to live in
- copy the working code over that checkout
- commit the lot

If you just need to have the current codebase in SVN, you could just import it after removing the .svn directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note that there will be a .svn directory in every subfolder. The command to get rid of them all is to right click in tortoisesvn and export it over itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout the tree to another location, then compare with Beyond Compare with a filter on the subversion dirs .svn  then check=in from the new tree.

Which is a lazy way of doing Criag's solution, with tools I already own.